# Javascript build tool to only create unique file names

Tags: javascript, webpack, rollupjs, build-tools, parceljs

I have a javascript project using ES6 modules and I want to be able to make an exact copy of the project, except with hashed filenames for static assets. So if the project lives in `/src` the whole thing might get copied over to `/dist` and if for example in `index.html` we have `<script src="index.js">` then this get's converted to `<script src="indexH7eF4VBakl8B.js">` and `index.js` get's copied over as `indexH7eF4VBakl8B.js`, similarly for `imports` within javascript and css files. Webpack, Rollup, and Parcel all do far more than I want to do. My question is, do any tools exist to do this or similar? If necessary I'll write my own tool to do this, but I obviously don't want to if somebody else already has.

Comment: Webpack with HTMLWebpackPlugin should work... all your js files will be bundled